# How to include external javascript file in a facelet page?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In a Facelet page that uses a Facelet Template like this:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript name="custom.js" library="javascript" target="head"/>
</h:head>
<ui:composition template="../../WEB-INF/Template.xhtml">

</ui:composition>
```

How do you include a custom javascript?  In the code above my custom.js is ignored because
of the ui:composition facelet tag.

I dont want to mess my page by putting my javascript in it so I am externalizing it in my resources
folder.

But how do I achieve my goal?

**UPDATE:**

I basically have this button and I wanted to add custom javascript on the oncomplete event of my primefaces button.

```
<p:commandButton value="Save"
        actionListener="#{memberManagedBean.save}"
        oncomplete="handleSaveNewMember(xhr, status, args)"
        update=":memberListForm:membersTable"
        process="@form" />
```

But instead of putting my code to it, I have externalize it to my custom.js

```
function handleSaveNewMember(xhr, status, args) {
    /*More Code*/
    addMemberDlg.hide();
}
```

But looking at the generated HTML for my button, my custom javascript codes are not included and only the function name is added.

```
<button id="createupdateform:j_idt18" oncomplete:function(xhr, status, args){handleSaveNewMember(xhr, status, args);}});return false;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text">Save</span></button>
```

Why do you think this is so?

**UPDATE 2**

You should insert the script inside the ui:define facelet tag not inside the ui:composition.

```
<ui:composition template="../../WEB-INF/Template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputScript name="showmembers.js" library="javascript" target="head"/>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place it inside your `<ui:composition`

```
<ui:composition template="../../WEB-INF/Template.xhtml">
    <h:outputScript name="custom.js" library="javascript" target="head"/>
</ui:composition>
```

or place `<h:outputScript` inside your `Template.xhtml`

anyway the `<h:head>` better be placed in your `Template.xhtml` only...

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks to this but can you still help with my problem? I have updated my post.

Comment: did my answer solved your original question ? about your new question you are no supposed to see your handleSaveNewMember code appended in to your button , its ok, it will be inside your js file... in the button you suppoed to see only the reference to the function name kust like you posted , you might need to click ctrl + F5 one time to refresh your js

Comment: Hi Daniel.. Sorry I am not sure if my question was really answered because my Dialog wasn't close when I clicked the button.  Nothing is really happening.  I am thinking that my code was not executed.

Comment: for start write a simple js method closeDialog(){addMemberDlg.hide();} and call it from oncomplete="closeDialog()" ofcourse you need to place it in your js file...

Comment: is it even being called ? closeDialog(){alert('hey')} you see the alert ?

Comment: Actually no... the alert is not called.  Also I notice from Firebug that it is not downloading my custom.js file... which leads me to thinking that it isn't downloading or using the file..

Comment: hahaha... I have updated my post.  Everything works now.! Thanks Daniel